# Why does IE9 enter compatibility mode with a span + :first-letter + text-transform:capitalize?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Here is a simple test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>why</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style>
        body:first-letter {
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span>*</span>
    œ blablabla (non-latin character on a new-line is also triggers that problem just like a single span with * without any characters following it)
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason IE9 reports that it has problems displaying that page and reloads the page in a compatibility mode. Why? What is the problem with that code?

If `<span>` changes to `<div>`, it works OK. If it changes to `<div>` with `display:inline` (same as span), then it reloads the page again. If `*` changes to `&nbsp;`, then everything is OK, even in `<span>`. So what doesn't IE9 like in that code?

Comment: Humorous title tag in your test case.

Answer (score 0):

The code is odd (though correct), because it tells the browser to capitalize the first letter of an element that contains no letters. Browsers have different interpretations on the meaning of `:first-letter` when the first character of the element content is not a letter; the specifications are vague and obscure in this matter. But this oddity is very odd. It’s a quirk that can probably be easily circumvented. Presumably, IE 9 goes wild in its attempt to determine the first letter when there is an intervening inline element.

On my IE 9, the page displays as completely black, in “standards mode”. Switching the browser to quirks mode makes the page display OK. In your case, possibly using a different minor version of IE 9, the browser might somehow detect that there is something wrong when operating in standards mode and therefore fall back to quirks mode.

Using `*a` as the `span` element content makes IE 9 display the page correctly with “*A”. So the bug seems to be caused by a rare combination of things that does not normally occur – normally there *is* a letter inside an element when you use `text-transform: capitalize`.

Comment: Well, that is just a testcase. On a live page where that problem appeared there are letters of course other than *.
* there is an optional character that defines "required" values and always precedes some caption (which must be capitalized). I don't think this is a very rare case.
Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: In my test, the problem does not appear if there is a letter in the content. Can you provide a test case that triggers the bug with such an element?

Comment: Yes, a problem appears if you would place some non-latin character (for example any russian character [Ы] or german [œ] or anything else) on the next line after the span (this is important for some unknown reason).
Update: well, actually not any non-latin character triggers that. I tested with German umlauts and they don't trigger that problem. However œ triggers the problem in my test case.